# C# linq statements

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to C# linq. Just wondering if it is possible to combine the following two linq statements into one.

```
var l = str.Split(new[] { '\n' },   
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(p => p.Trim())
        .Where(p =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
        .ToArray();
foreach (var w in l)    {    
     var dd = w.Split(new[] { ' ' },   
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Select(p => p.Trim())
     .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
     .Concat(new[] { "\n" });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you do with `dd`? As written this does nothing useful beyond assigning `l`. Do you care about the line structure or do you just want to split on space or newline (which Split can do on its own)?

Comment: @IanMercer, I am using dd to print out the statements to see if it really works. The line structure does matter, split by new line and then, for each new line, split by empty space.

Answer (score 3):

[SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) is your friend:

```
  var l = str.Split(new[] { '\n' },   
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(p => p.Trim())
    .Where(p =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .SelectMany(w => w.Split(new[] { ' ' },  ringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(p => p.Trim())
    .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .Concat(new[] { "\n" });
```

Comment: that'll work , except the fact that `RemoveEmptyEntries` and `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)`  is a little redundant

Answer (score 0):

If all you care about is a bag of words, use `string.Split` and pass it both the newline character and the space character, there is no need to do this in two steps and to combine them using `SelectMany`.

If however you want to capture the line structure somehow in what you are processing, e.g. to create a sequence of sequences representing the lines and the words on each line then use `Select` again.

```
var l = str.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(p => p.Trim())
    .Where(p =>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
    .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(p => p.Trim())
      .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p)));
```

l is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.